# Prevent JOption from blocking child JFrame

Tags: java

Is there a possibility to prevent a JOptionPane dialog from blocking the interaction with the rest of the program, especially child JFrames? In my GUI, I launch a JFrame and want a message dialog to pop up after the child is closed to remind the user of something, but they launch parallel and the reminder blocks the child frame from being used.

Like here:

```
popupObjMan newPopup1 = new popupObjMan(gatewayAbstract, gatewayAbstractID);     
        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(this, "REMINDER: DO REFRESH");
```

I've tried to set the popup always on top, but this doesn't quite do the job.
I have no problem with them launching parallel (I'd even prefer it), but I could not work my head around it yet.

I just started Java programming ,so sorry in case that'd be something obvious.

Comment: You got yesterday two answers. Please consider upvoting/accepting them.

Comment: @Melvin I upvoted both of them, but since I dont have enough reputation yet, my upvotes won't get displayed.

Comment: Thx. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JOptionPane normally need to be modal. It shows something important and waits till the user answers with whatever option you give him (e.g. ok-button, yes/no-buttons, ...)

But there are several ways to reach your target.

(a)
Normally a JOptionPane creates a modal window.
You need a modeless window which does not block other windows.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

(b)
You can start different threads to work for your different windows. They can have windows which are shown whenever the responsible thread commands them to. This is a bit difficult and can lead to memory-troubles.

(c)
You can write your own message-panels (e.g. notificaton) which are shown when and how long you like.

Bigger projects use different of these ways to achieve their goals.

Answer (score 0):

A `JOptionPane` is a component, just like a JPanel. As a component it can be added to any other panel.

The `JOptionPane` API provides static methods to create a show the `JOptionPane` on a modal `JDialog` by default. You can't change this behaviour.

However, you can manually add the `JOptionPane` to a non-modal `JDialog` that you create. This is extra work as you now need to handle the closing of the dialog and processing the clicked button.

If you really want to do this then read the `JOptionPane` API. There is a section on `Direct Use` which demonstrates the basic code needed to add the `JOptionPane` to a `JDialog`.